# Matlab Subscript indices error, runs perfectly interactively

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a matlab script that loops recursively through a directory and tries to find all the files of a certain type. I'm using an array as a sort of stack.

The line

```
dirstack{end + 1} = filesInCurrentDir(i);
```

fails. However, if I use `dbstop if error` and run the exact same line, word for word, by hand, it works fine.

It also fails if I preassign an index to `length(dirstack) + 1`

Is there a reason this wouldn't work in a script environment but it would in an interactive environment?

Minimum working example:

```
DIR='.';
dirstack{1} = DIR;
while length(dirstack) ~= 0 %loop while there's still directories to look for
    curdir = dirstack{1}; %the working directory is popped off the top of the stack
    dirstack{1} = []; %delete the top element, finishing the pop operation
    filesInCurrentDir = dir(curdir);
    for i=3:length(filesInCurrentDir) % start at 3, dir returns 1:. 2:.. and we don't want those
        if filesInCurrentDir(i).isdir; %if this is a directory
            dirstack{end+1} = filesInCurrentDir(i);
        elseif strcmp(filesInCurrentDir(i).name(end+[-3:0], '.jpg')) == 1 %if it's a psdata file
            files{end+1} = [curdir, filesep, filesInCurrentDir(i_.name)];   
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would get all .jpg files under current folder and its subfolders:

```
dirs = genpath(pwd); % dir with subfolders
dirs = strsplit(dirs, pathsep); % in cellstr for each dir
files = {};
for i = 1:numel(dirs)
    curdir = [dirs{i} filesep];
    foo = dir([curdir '*.jpg']); % all jpg files
    foo([foo.isdir]) = []; % just in case .jpg is folder name
    foo = strcat(curdir, {foo.name}); % full file names
    files = [files foo]; % cell growing
end
```

Now back to your question. There are several place of error in your code. You can  compare to my corrected code and check my comments in the code:

```
dirstack = {pwd}; % ensure init dirstack to current dir
files = {};
while length(dirstack) ~= 0 % better ~isempty(dirstack)
    curdir = dirstack{1};
    dirstack(1) = []; % dirstack{1} = [] sets first cell to [], wont remove the cell as you want
    filesInCurrentDir = dir(curdir);
    for i=3:length(filesInCurrentDir) % this works for Windows, but may not be safe to always skip first two
        if filesInCurrentDir(i).isdir
            dirstack{end+1} = filesInCurrentDir(i);
        elseif strcmp(filesInCurrentDir(i).name(end+[-3:0]), '.jpg') == 1 % had error here
            files{end+1} = [curdir, filesep, filesInCurrentDir(i).name]; % had error here
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the new method. I still don't understand why I'm having the original issue? Especially because the exact line runs properly interactively, and it doesn't look like you found any issues with it?

Comment: I explained the error in the comment of the code. One major error is to use dirstack(1) rather than dirstack{1} when you remove a cell element. Others are like syntax error or typo (I labelled with "had error here"). The error message is likely due to the syntax error. So I don't believe your minimum example works line by line.